# Prove that $f(\gamma) \leq 0$ using property of continuity - proof check

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Suppose that a function $f$ is continuous from the left at a point $\gamma$ and there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x) < 0$ whenever $\gamma - \delta < x < \gamma$. Prove that $f(\gamma) \leq 0$.

I don't feel completely sure of the step to take that I believe would solve the question. So given all of the conditions above we arrive at this expression w.r.t continuity:

$$|f(x) - f(\gamma)| < \epsilon \\ \ -\epsilon < f(x) - f(\gamma) < \epsilon$$

In this scenario the common thing to so is just manipulate $f(\gamma)$, but this time around we have to show the property holds for $f(\gamma)$. What I want to do is:

$$ -f(x) - \epsilon < -f(\gamma) < \epsilon - f(x) \\ f(x) + \epsilon > f(\gamma) > f(x) - \epsilon$$

Now since we were given $f(x) < 0$ then if I let $\epsilon = f(x)$ I could satisfy the property, but what makes me uncomfortable about this solution is the whole process of manipulating $f(x)$ in the first place...that is not a fixed value and it doesn't feel right to treat it as such. Am I wrong in thinking this?

Comment: I agree @J.Doe, this is why it felt weird to me to try and solve the question in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not correct. If you take $\epsilon =  f(x)$, then $\epsilon <0$.

Suppose that $f(\gamma)>0$. Since $f(x)$ is left-hand continuous, $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists \delta_1 >0$ such that for all $x$, if $\gamma -x <\delta_1$, then $|f(x)-f(\gamma)|<\epsilon$, i.e., $-\epsilon < f(x)-f(\gamma)<\epsilon$. Take $\epsilon  = f(\gamma)/2$, $\exists \delta ^\prime >0 $ such that $f(x)>f(\gamma)/2>0$ when $\gamma - \delta ^\prime <x\le \gamma$.

Now take $\delta_2 =min\{\delta, \delta ^\prime\}$. The given condition says that $f(x)<0$ when $\gamma-\delta_2<x<\gamma$, while the paragraph above shows $f(x)>0$ when $\gamma-\delta_2<x<\gamma$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Is there a direct approach to establish this or only by contradiction?